# How to import over 10 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I want to import 10 million insert statements.
The queries are in one big SQL file (861 MB).
Currently, I am using the MySQL import option with Linux.
But it took too much time for it. 
I need a faster method to import my big .sql file.

I am using this command right now:

```
mysql -u root -p -h localhost database < file.sql
```

Comment: what commands are you using to attempt the import?

Comment: Only insert commands

Comment: Yes, but you said you were using the mysql import option. Which one is that? What command are you using on the console?

Comment: sry, this one: `mysql -u root -p -h localhost database < file.sql`

Comment: Have you read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-speed.html (and its sub-pages)? It has a lot of good tips.